# Auto Complete with characters of an array in IOS

Tags: ios, autocomplete, uitextfield

I have a textfield in which user can enter car names, I want it tout complete with the suggested name under it in tableview, I have tried some code but it is having some issues, when first time I enter any character like "Honda" it shows all the items in an array, instead of items with name related of Honda. And once when we type any word it shows list and if we try to again re type it does not show any list.

My code is this:

```
_carTable.dataSource=self;
_carTable.delegate=self;


[self.guideView addSubview:_carTable];

_carTable.hidden=YES;

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

NSLog(@"Range:%@",NSStringFromRange(range));
NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);

NSString *passcode = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

NSLog(@"%@",passcode);


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"SELF CONTAINS %@",passcode];
carArray = [carArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", carArray);

if ([carArray count]==0) {
    _carTable.hidden = TRUE;
}else{
    _carTable.hidden = FALSE;
}

[_carTable reloadData];


return TRUE;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used single carArray array then it is having some issues so please go with global array.

Edit 1:

In your .h file -

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray * staticCarArray;
```

In.m file-

@synthesize sharedArray;

In viewDidLoad -

```
staticCarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
staticCarArray = [carArray mutableCopy];
```

Edit 2: 
textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange this method change your code for it.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                      @"SELF CONTAINS %@",passcode];
carArray = [staticCarArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%@", carArray);
```

Comment: i have globally declare NSArray like this  NSArray *carArray; . Just i have to edit this line in my method ? NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF CONTAINS %@",passcode];

carArray = [staticCarArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

NSLog(@"%@", carArray); . @Navneet Baldha

Comment: do you assign staticCarArray?  and add all object in this staticCarArray?

Add both line on your code.

    staticCarArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    staticCarArray = [carArray mutableCopy];

Comment: yes now its perfectly working, thats what i want . :) . @Navneet Baldha

Comment: can we use the same method with another textfield in same class? @Navneet Baldha

Comment: Okay Great!!  Yes you used same method with another textfield in same class

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your array variable `carArray` is not getting reset from somewhere else in the code?

The reason that you are getting the list of all the cars in your table is because tableView is still getting the complete car array which is not filtered.

Comment: No its not getting reset, but i have passed basic datasource method for tableview to populate the tableview with array. @Gurdev Singh